# Recursive grep with include giving incorrect results for current folder

Tags: linux, grep

I have created a test directory structure:
t1.html
t2.php
a/t1.html
a/t2.php
b/t1.html
b/t2.php

All files contain the string "HELLO".

The following commands are run from the root folder above:

```
> grep -r "HELLO" *
b/t1.html:HELLO
b/t2.php:HELLO
c/t1.html:HELLO
c/t2.php:HELLO
t1.html:HELLO
t2.php:HELLO

> grep -r --include=*.html "HELLO" *
b/t1.html:HELLO
c/t1.html:HELLO
t2.php:HELLO
```

Why is it including the correct .html files from the sub-directories, but the .php file from the current directory?

If I pop up a level to the directory above my whole structure, then it gives following result:

```
grep -r --include=*.html "HELLO" *
a/t1.html:HELLO
a/c/t1.html:HELLO
a/b/t1.html:HELLO
```

This is what I expected when ran from within my structure.

I assume I can achieve the goal using find+grep together, but I thought this was valid usage of grep.

Thanks for any help.

Andy

Comment: You may want to investigate my greplike tool `ack` which simplifies these sorts of common searches.  Your example would be `ack --html HELLO`.  http://beyondgrep.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dot instead of the asterisk:

```
grep -r HELLO .
```

Asterisk gets evaluated by the shell and replaced with the list of all the files in the current directory (whose names don't start with a dot). All of them are then grepped recursively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this worked perfectly. I'm still not quite clear on why it returns the files from current directory that don't match the expression from the current directory (rather than all or none of the files) but the . fixed the problem.

Comment: @AndyHall: With the asterisk, your command is equivalent to `grep -r --include=*.html "HELLO" b c t1.html t2.php`. Do you see the last argument?